# Let $V = \{x \in \mathbf{R}^3 \mid x_1+2x_2 -x_3=0 \}.$ Determine $\dim V$.

Tags: linear-algebra

> Let $V = \{x \in \mathbf{R}^3 \mid x_1+2x_2 -x_3=0 \}.$ Determine $\dim V$.

The dimension is the number of vectors in the basis set. Here $x_1,x_2$ and $x_3$ are scalars not vectors so how can the dimension be determined here? Also $x_3 = x_1+2x_2$ so $x_3$ is a linear combination of $x_1$ and $x_2$. This somehow suggest that $\dim V = 2$, but I'm not sure. What can I do?

Comment: Do you know the rank-nulity theorem?

Comment: I do, but is that necessary here?

Comment: Heuristically, each linear restriction aka each "=" sign reduces the dimension of the space by $1$ because it reduces the number of free variables by $1$

Comment: Necessary? No, but very convenient :) it is just the kernel of the map $x\mapsto (1,2,-1)x$. The image is 1-dim and thus the kernel is 2d.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Observe that each vector $x \in V$ can be written on the form

$$\begin{bmatrix} 
x_1 \\
x_2 \\
x_1 + 2x_2 \end{bmatrix} = x_1 \begin{bmatrix} 
1 \\ 
0 \\ 
1\\ \end{bmatrix} + x_2 \begin{bmatrix} 
0 \\
1 \\
2 \end{bmatrix}$$

Hence, these two vectors span $V$. They are clearly linearly independent, so they form a basis, and the dimension is 2.

Rank-Nullity Theorem-Approach: Observe that $V$ is the null space of the matrix

$$A = \begin{bmatrix} 
1 & 2 & -1 \\
0 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0 \end{bmatrix}.$$

$A$ is clearly a rank 1 matrix, so by the Rank-Nullity Theorem

$$\dim V = \dim (\text{Nul} (A)) = 3-\text{rank}(A)=2$$

Answer (score 1):

$V=\{x\in\mathbb{R}^3\,|\,x\cdot(1,2,-1)=0\}$.

Thus, $V$ is the plane that contains the origin and is orthogonal to $(1,2,-1)$.
Hence, $\dim V=2$.

Answer (score 0):

From a direct isomorphism: the linear map
\begin{align}
\mathbf R^2&\longrightarrow \mathbf R^3,\\
(x_1,x_2)&\longmapsto (x_1, x_2, x_1+2x_2),
\end{align}
is injective and its image is $V$, so it induces an isomorphism from $\mathbf R^2$ onto $V$ by restriction of the codomain.

Answer (score 0):

The most elementary argument I can think of is the following.

The dimension can be at most $2$ since there are vectors that do not satisfy that relation, e.g. $(1,0,0)$.

On the other hand, $V$ contains at least two linearly independent vectors, e.g. $(1,0,1)$ and $(2,-1,0)$.

Hence the dimension must be $2$.